# Socket Programming in Python Either Returning Error 10061 or Leaving My Server Not Receiving Data

Tags: python, sockets

Working on learning socket programming and I am having a strange issue crop up between my two codes depending on what IP I try to run them through.

Server:

```python
import socket
import time
import datetime
import filecmp

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 9100

n = 1
x = 0
average_list = []

print('I am ready for any client side request \n')

file_comparison = "send.txt"

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

s.bind((HOST,PORT))

s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()

while n <= 100:

  data = conn.recv(1024)

  file = 'receive1.txt';

  print('I am starting receiving file', file,'for the',n,'th time')

  a = datetime.datetime.now()

  f = open(file, 'wb')

  f.write(data)

  print('I am finishing receiving file', file,'for the',n,'th time')

  b = datetime.datetime.now()

  rawtime = b - a

  millidelta = rawtime * 1000

  average_list.append(millidelta)

  real_average = ((sum(average_list, datetime.timedelta(0,0))) / n)

  print('The time used in milliseconds to receive',file,'for the',n,'th time','is:',millidelta,'milliseconds')

  print('The average time to receive',file,'in milliseconds is:',real_average)

  if filecmp.cmp(file,file_comparison,shallow=False):

    x = x+1

  n=n + 1

f.close()

conn.close()

s.close()

print('I am done \n')

print('Total errors: ',x,'out of',n-1 )
```

Client:

```python
import socket
import datetime
import time
import filecmp

#initializing host, port, filename, total time and number of times to send the file

host = 'localhost'

port = 9100

fileName = "send.txt"

n = 1

average_list = []

file_to_send = open(fileName,'rb')

while n <= 100:

    data = file_to_send.read(1024)

    s=socket.socket()

    s.connect((host,port))

    s.sendall(data)

    #reading the next 1024 bits

    print('I am connecting to server side:',host,'\n')

    print('I am sending file',fileName,'for the',n,'th time')

    a = datetime.datetime.now()

    print('I am finishing sending file',fileName,'for the',n,'th time')

    b = datetime.datetime.now()

    rawtime = b - a

    millidelta = rawtime * 1000

    average_list.append(millidelta)

    real_average = ((sum(average_list, datetime.timedelta(0,0))) / n)

    print('The time used in milliseconds to send',fileName,'for the',n,'th time','is:',millidelta,'milliseconds')

    print('The average time to send',fileName,'in milliseconds is:',real_average)

    n = n + 1

file_to_send.close()

s.close()



print('I am done')
```

In this current iteration my client side code simply runs through the loop trying to send the data of a .txt file to a server that isnt receiving anything.  If i change 'localhost' to my actual IP address, I instead get the server side code cycling through its while loop while the client side gives up after 2 iterations with:

ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

with the error citing line 15, "s.connect((host,port)) as the cause of the issue.  Ultimately Im stuck since changing my host between what I assumed were two correct implementations of the host are giving me drastically different results with neither working as intended.

Comment: are you sure you dont have another copy running on localhost:9100 ... try changing the port to something else 9121 or something in both files, then start the server then start the client ... use localhost or 127.0.0.1 as the ip for the client, and use 0.0.0.0 as the ip for the server

Comment: Remember that, socket connects happen per net card.  If your server binds to `localhost`, then it's only going to be listening on the localhost interface.  It won't listed on the outside IP address, even if that goes to the same computer.  You have to bind to `"0.0.0.0"` if you want it to listen on all interfaces.

Comment: hi there. I made the alterations you suggested and it swung back around to producing a WinError 10061 on my client side code @Joran Beasley

Answer (score 0):

What I think the error is trying to tell us from other times I have seen that is that the port the socket is trying to connect is still connected to another socket.

So my diagnosis of why that might be happening is that the `s.close()` is not in the while loop so it keeps making a new socket and then tries to connect on the same port.

Edit: I got a chance to run it on my side and it works for me if I pull the whole making and binding of a socket out of the loop like this:

```
import socket
import datetime
import time
import filecmp

#initializing host, port, filename, total time and number of times to send the file

host = 'localhost'

port = 9100

fileName = "send.txt"

n = 1

average_list = []

file_to_send = open(fileName,'rb')

s=socket.socket()

s.connect((host,port))  
while n <= 100:
    data = file_to_send.read(1024)
    s.sendall(data)

    #reading the next 1024 bits

    print('I am connecting to server side:',host,'\n')

    print('I am sending file',fileName,'for the',n,'th time')

    a = datetime.datetime.now()

    print('I am finishing sending file',fileName,'for the',n,'th time')

    b = datetime.datetime.now()

    rawtime = b - a

    millidelta = rawtime * 1000

    average_list.append(millidelta)

    real_average = ((sum(average_list, datetime.timedelta(0,0))) / n)

    print('The time used in milliseconds to send',fileName,'for the',n,'th time','is:',millidelta,'milliseconds')

    print('The average time to send',fileName,'in milliseconds is:',real_average)

    n = n + 1
s.close()
file_to_send.close()
```

This definitely works for me and sends the file 100 times and it gets received 100 times but I don't know if in your use case you need it to be a hundred new sockets instead of one socket sending 100 files that get successfully received.

Comment: Unfortunately moving s.close() into the while loops did not change the outcome. WinError 10061 still shows up after 1 iteration.

Comment: Just an update Eliyah, the code runs, but it is simply cycling through the while loop. no files are being created or edited in any way.  This was my initial issue as I thought I had gotten the code to work, but it only compiles and cycles through saying it is completing the processes while actually doing nothing on the back end.